# what is the difference between T& and T&& in template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, reference

What is the difference between T& and T&& in template parameter? For example:

```
template<class T> void f(T& t) {...}
template<class T> void f(T&& t) {...}
```

I try the code

```
template<class T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    t = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    f(a); //a == 5 why?        
    return 0;
}
```

I expect a = 0 but = 5, why?

Comment: What compiler is this using, I've just trued gcc 4.8.1 and it won't compile with ambiguous warning, which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, whatever `T` is, `t` is always an lvalue reference:

```
T = U     =>   T & = U &
T = U &   =>   T & = U &
T = U &&  =>   T & = U &
```

In the second case, `t` may be an lvalue *or* rvalue reference. In other words, `t` is *always* a reference, but it can bind to any argument. It's a ["universal" reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers):

```
T = U     =>   T && = U &&
T = U &   =>   T && = U &
T = U &&  =>   T && = U &&
```

When you call the second template `f(g())`, then `T` is deduced as an lvalue reference if `g()` is an lvalue, and as a non-reference otherwise.

In your example `f(a)`, since `a` is an lvalue, `T` is deduced as `int &`, so `T && = int &`, and so the function parameter `t` is bound to the object `a`, which you then modify.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand rightly. Please see my example testing. Thanks.

Comment: Added link to Scott Meyers on universal references, not sure if that's best but it's something.

Comment: @user1899020: I added a sentence addressing your example.